# Does stroke add on the outside or inside of an object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke

I'm working on the front panel of a product at my company and I have an old physical model that I have to work off of.

It has white outlines around a couple switches etc. These outlines have approximately a 10px stroke around them. The shapes are inset from the edges so I'm using a caliper to figure out exactly where to place my guides in Photoshop (so when they have these cut out they will fit perfectly on the product).

However, because of the stroke, I realized I'm not sure if I should make my measurement from the bottom edge, inner edge, or from the center of the line because I'm not sure exactly how Ps applies strokes to objects.

I looked at Adobe's guide page on fill and strokes but they just tell me how to add a stroke.

[image: where should I measure?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strokes can be applied to the inside, center, or outside of a path.

Open the Properties window for the path you wish to adjust the stroke on (Window > Properties) and click on the Alignment drop down

[image]

For layers that are not paths or shapes, you will need to open the layer's effects and edit the stroke alignment there

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this existed. Thanks very much!